# emond process running at 100%

Tags: mac-osx-server, daemon

I have a couple of XServes running 10.5.6 and both of them have emond running at 100%. 
If the servers are rebooted emond will not immediately consume 100%, but it will eventually.

I haven't seen anything unusual in the logs, does anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the configuration files to see what you have set up:

1) Check `/etc/emond.d/rules`, and `/etc/emond.d/emond.plist`

In the plist you can turn the debug on, and then check the apropriate logs at `/Library/Logs/EventMonitor/EventMonitor.event.log`

2) Alternatively you can run `sudo fs_usage emond` to take a look at just what files emond is accessing in real time.

3) If you want to disable emond to see what breaks when you turn it off run `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.emond.plist`

Oddly the best documentation I've ever seen on emond is on a thread at [discussions.apple.com](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1314366) from late 2007 to do with Leopard Server.